# When trying to include " in a String, using \" works but the \ is included too

Tags: xcode, string, swift, string-formatting

I'm trying to send a string to an Http request using the following code

```
var outStr = "{product_code: \"660825\", quantity: \(qty)}"
```

As I've included the \ character it compiles ok but when I run it the value for outStr is

```
{product_code: \"660825\", quantity: 2}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I lose the \?

Comment: Try \\", this will escape the backslash too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html):

> String literals can include the following special characters:
>
> The escaped special characters \0 (null character), \ (backslash), \t
>   (horizontal tab), \n (line feed), \r (carriage return), \" (double
>   quote) and \' (single quote)

(snip)

```
let wiseWords = "\"Imagination is more important than knowledge\" - Einstein"
// "Imagination is more important than knowledge" - Einstein
```

you are doing it correctly, my guess would be that you server escapes the `"` as `\"` and that is why you are seeing `{product_code: \"660825\", quantity: 2}`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that makes sense, so the string passed is actually the correct {product_code: "660825", quantity: 2} so I don't need to change anything?

Comment: Well, that depends. If you are expecting `{product_code: "660825", quantity: 2}`, but you are getting `{product_code: \"660825\", quantity: 2}`, I would check if there is a bug at the server-side, or if you double escape the HTTP-request or the received data.

Comment: I may have misled you because when I step through the code in debug, I check the string shortly before I pass it to the Http request and the value in debug includes the \ character as displayed above. I assume that means that is what is passed to our server. In which case I need to take steps to remove them.